Unable to connect to kafka cluster from docker client
My spring boot app is able to connect to kafka cluster hosted on cloud when app is run locally. but when i deploy app using docker image, it refuses to connect to kafka cluster, provided the environment variables i passed during deployment are correct. How can i resolve this?
This is my docker file
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/realtimechatapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar realtimechatapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/realtimechatapp.jar"]

I suspect network configurations, or kafka cluster address which may not be directly accessible from the Docker container without proper configuration.

We need more details. Does the container run locally? The network issue could be in your deployment environment, not your container. What environment variables? What configuration are you trying to set?

No it's not running locally. I deployed my application on render using docker image, and then sending the environment variables which we do set in our application.properties. It includes kafka cluster details, kafka properties, redis cluster props, database conenction details etc.

Have you allowed incoming connections from the Render network to your cluster? https://docs.render.com/static-outbound-ip-addresses

My kafka cluster is hosted on upstash. Sadly i coudn't find anything on the platform to allow configuration for render's outbound addresses :(

If you can run your container locally with the necessary environment variables, and it works there, then I suggest contacting upstash or Render support for assistance, since that would mean the problem is not in your code, or the container

Hi, can you confirm you have followed similar steps as this blog post: https://upstash.com/blog/render-serverless-redis ?
